# Kotlin Android studio New Version

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

When i am using android studio new version with below new method for project level gradle app level gradle dependency not working. Thanks in advance

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
}
}

plugins {
  id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
  id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

Comment: What does the output says when you are trying to sync/build?

Comment: Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

Comment: Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/tonyodev/fetch2/fetch2/3.0.12/fetch2-3.0.12.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Comment: Well, it seems that the file requires authorization, which you either don't have or have not set up.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. if i remove project level gradle contain for google service its working fine.

Comment: Look like only problem with library .. remaning all libraryr working fine. Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/tonyodev/fetch2/fetch2/3.0.12/fetch2-3.0.12.pom'.